# How to empty a string in Arduino c language

Tags: c++, c, string, arduino

I wrote the below in arduino code language (c or c++ ?)
And i got puzled, i'm not sure if this is a limitation from C or C++.
My function should split a text string and return word number x
In my function i need to clean a string variable, that resets its contend until X is reached
For readability X is called wordcount.

How do i clean the string Wordsample make it empty again ?
On a side note, if the word isnt found then this function should also return nothing 
As the results are used to make other strings from.

```
String GetSubString (String A,int Wordcount) //for readability start counting B from 1
{   int CounterX;
String WordSampleN;
String result ;
for (int i = 0; i < A.length(); i++)
{   // split string
    WordSampleN = WordSampleN + A[i];
    if ((A[i] == ' ') || (A[i] =='\n'))
    {   CounterX++;
        if (CounterX == Wordcount)
        {   result = WordSampleN;
        }
        if (CounterX <> WordCount)
        {   WordSampleN = '';  //  <== ERROR IS HERE 
        }
    }
}
return result;}
```

On a side note, if possible I would like to keep use strings of any size, not fixed strings.

Comment: Besides some other errors in the code that didnt make it work.
I think you where right double quotes worked.
Kinda strange dough because A[i] == '\n' with single quotes was ok too, perhaps mixed some language syntaxes here, which is not a good practice

Comment: You can use single quotes as long as you are in fact referring to a single character, but not a string consisting of no characters. See my answer below and accept if you think it's ok.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no concept of an 'empty character'. You cannot initialize your String (object) this way. Instead, use an empty (small-"s") string "";

```
WordSampleN = "";
```

This will call the String constructor that takes a c-style string, and initialize your String object with the empty string.